# Laravel - How to prevent delete when there is dependent field

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have these models

HrGradeLevel

```
class HrGradeLevel extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'hr_grade_levels';

  protected $fillable = [
              'grade_level_code',
              'grade_level_name',
              'description',
          ];

  public function designation(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hr\HrDesignation');
  }

  public function employee(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee');
  }  
}
```

HrDesignation

```
class HrDesignation extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'hr_designations';

  protected $fillable = [
              'designation_name',
              'grade_level_id',
          ];

  protected $casts = [];

  public function gradelevel()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrGradeLevel','grade_level_id');
  }
}
```

HrEmployee

```
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'hr_employees';

  protected $fillable = [
              'first_name',
      'last_name',
              'grade_level_id',
          ];

  protected $casts = [];

  public function gradelevel()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrGradeLevel','grade_level_id');
  }
}
```

HrDesignation and HrEmployee has foreign key grade_level_id that is derived from HrGradeLevel

HrGradeLevelController

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    $grade = HrGradeLevel::find($id);
    $grade->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'Grade Level deleted successfully.');
    return redirect()->route('hr.grade_level.index');
}
```

From the Controller above, the user can delete HrGradeLevel row.

Using Laravel, before the user is allowed to delete I want the application to check HrDesignation and HrEmployee, if any of them have data in grade_level_id, I want the application to display a message and it shouldn't allow delete.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use [foreign key constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) on your migrations and MySQL will prevent deleting a record if foreign key is used on other tables/records by default:

   ```php
   public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
   {
       $grade = HrGradeLevel::find($id);

       try {
           $grade->delete();
       }
       catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
           if ($e->getCode() == 23000)
           {
               //SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation
               abort('Resource cannot be deleted due to existence of related resources.');
           }
       }

       Session::flash('success', 'Grade Level deleted successfully.');
       return redirect()->route('hr.grade_level.index');
   }
   ```
2. Check existence of your relationships before deleting:

   ```php
   public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
   {
       $grade = HrGradeLevel::find($id);

       if ($grade->designation()->exists()
           || $grade->employee()->exists())
       {
           abort('Resource cannot be deleted due to existence of related resources.');
       }

       $grade->delete();
       Session::flash('success', 'Grade Level deleted successfully.');
       return redirect()->route('hr.grade_level.index');
   }
   ```

Comment: This will not work when using soft delete