# How to restrict delete / destroy method when model has association with another model / id?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have model called **GroupService** and it has association with **Service**. I want to prevent or restrict when deleting **GroupService**, if **GroupService** has association with **Service**. And if **GroupService** has no association then users can delete it. I've been following these guides but it's not working for me :

[1] [Laravel - How to prevent delete when there is dependent field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578308/laravel-how-to-prevent-delete-when-there-is-dependent-field)

[2] https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-prevent-the-delete-of-table-row-that-has-its-id-in-another-table

Here's my code :

Model GroupService:

```php
class GroupService extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 't_grup_layanan';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'bisnis_id',
    //     'deskripsi'
    // ];
    protected $with = ['business'];

    public function service(){
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }

    public function business(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Business::class, 'bisnis_id');
    }
    
    // protected static function boot(){
    //     parent::boot();

    //     static::deleting(function($groupservice) {
    //         $relationMethods = ['service'];

    //         foreach ($relationMethods as $relationMethod) {
    //             if ($groupservice->$relationMethod()->count() > 0) {
    //                 return false;
    //             }
    //         }
    //     });
    // }

}
```

Model Service:

```php
class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 't_layanan';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'gruplayanan_id',
    //     'nama',
    //     'deskripsi'
    // ];
    protected $with = ['groupservice'];

    public function groupservice(){
        return $this->belongsTo(GroupService::class, 'gruplayanan_id');
    }
}
```

Controller GroupService:

```php
public function destroy(GroupService $groupservice, $id)
    {
    $groupService = GroupService::find(Crypt::decrypt($id));

        if ($groupService->service()->exists())
        {
            abort('Resource cannot be deleted due to existence of related     resources.');
        }

        $groupService->delete();

        return redirect('/dashboard/gruplayanan/')->with('danger', 'Data dihapus !');
        
        }
```

Migration GroupService:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('t_grup_layanan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('bisnis_id')->nullable()->index('fk_bisnis_to_group');
            $table->text('deskripsi');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
```

Migration Service:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('t_layanan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('gruplayanan_id')->index('fk_grup_to_layanan');
            $table->text('nama');
            $table->text('deskripsi');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('t_layanan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('gruplayanan_id', 'fk_grup_to_layanan')->references('id')->on('t_grup_layanan')->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just set all dependencies on the sql level as `nullable` that will prevent you a shot in the leg problem,  when accidentally 1 row has been deleted and cascaded 10-100 rows of record as well.Keep that it mind.

Comment: Does your code produces errors?

Comment: @aceraven777 yes

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco there's seems to be not changing anything, and i've still got my problems

Comment: okay what's the error? How can we help if you don't provide us the error details?

Comment: @aceraven777 https://imgur.com/y2VRGI7

Comment: It should be `abort(403);`, `abort(404);` or `abort(406);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here on your relationship function:

```
public function service(){
    return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
}
```

By Laravel convention, Eloquent will take the table name parent model and suffix it with `_id`.

So it look for `t_grup_layanan_id` field in the `t_layanan` table which currently does not exist.

So if you want to override the default convention, you have to specify it on the 2nd parameter like this.

```
public function service(){
    return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'gruplayanan_id');
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution, but i get these :

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::__construct(): Argument #1 ($statusCode) must be of type int, string given, called in

Comment: Called in what? Can you provide the whole error message?

Comment: https://imgur.com/y2VRGI7

Comment: I think the error you provided is not related to the issue. Kindly debug, find that `$statusCode` in your code.